# read xml nodes use javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

## How to console xml nodes like D area not A area use B code.

[image]

### javascript code

[image]

### console

[image]

#### Thanks everyone

### Update

[image]

Comment: why can't you just open up the node with everything inside it?

Comment: hi,watson. I upload another picture . How can i do . Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since 'childNodes'  returns all the child nodes under a node, so you are getting #text nodes along with element nodes.

And in your file there are a lot of #text nodes(caused due to linefeed, after each line). So apparently there is a #text node after each element node.

Simply: You can use 'children' instead of 'childNodes' property. 'children' only returns the element nodes.

Comment: Thanks you Bhaskar Melkani . It is not working when i use 'children' instead of 'childNodes'.  The node of "Text" appear in chorme/firfox not ie browser.

Comment: Oh ok...I did not checked in IE.